# Embed angular 2 app inside a web component (i.e. polymer)

Tags: angularjs, web, polymer, components

I've been looking around for this for quite a bit now, and to me it seems like there's no real approach so far.

So what I want to achieve is basically to encapsulate an angular 2 (or react, vue, whatever JS framework) app / component inside of a web component, best case would be a polymer component. 
The cause would be to easily reuse the component written in let's say angular 2, maybe even together with components written in other frameworks.

Maybe there's sth wrong with my basic understanding of WC, but I consider any combination of JS, HTML and CSS to be embeddable inside a WC. Any JS framework is not really anything else in the end, right? So shouldn't this be possible, at least in a very hacky way?

I hope this is enough to understand what I'm trying to do, any help is highly appreciated. As I said, I've been looking around already, so if someone knows any references that might answer the question, perfect.

Comment: Even if it would be possible, would it make sense? Building a whole Angular2 application and include it into a WC doesn't make sense to me. What if you want to use 5 such components in your application - then you have to load 5 full Angular2 applications. The other way around works out of the box - to use Polymer components in Angular because WC are lightweight and designed to be reused that way, but Angular isn't.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I totally get your point, and doing this is definitely some kind of workaround. The idea is to encapsulate only a small (reusable) component and build precisely this component with for example angular 2, maybe bc it's been built in another project already. I used 'app' bc you need the whole app in order to make angular run. If the app you are working on was already an angular app you would typically just include the component, but this is supposed to work more generic and potentially for multiple frameworks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this being said, it basically has to be like this, WC being the outside 'layer', cause they work based on the platform without much overhead. The other way round wouldn't make much sense in my particular case.

Comment: It might work but I think you should try to avoid it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the input! I'll keep that in mind, maybe I'll find another solution. Any ideas where to look or start though (For my current approach)?

Comment: Haven't seen this approach mentioned anywhere yet. Just try and post a question when you run into a concrete problem.